# Responding to node selection

Tags: java

I just copied the example code from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html (Responding to node selection) into mine as follows

```
public class IHM_PRO_CHIC extends JFrame implements ActionListener,KeyListener {

public IHM_PRO_CHIC () {
    super();
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    cree_ihm();
    };

private void cree_ihm() {

        DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("CHIC");
        Tree tree = new Tree (tree_file,top);
        JScrollPane treeView = new JScrollPane(tree);
        treeView.setVisible(true);  
        pane.add("Center",treeView);
        pane.setVisible(true);

        tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);        
        tree.addTreeSelectionListener(this);

};

public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
//Returns the last path element of the selection.
//This method is useful only when the selection model allows a single selection.
DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)
                   tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();

if (node == null)
//Nothing is selected.     
return;

Object nodeInfo = node.getUserObject();
if (node.isLeaf()) {
    BookInfo book = (BookInfo)nodeInfo;
    displayURL(book.bookURL);
} else {
    displayURL(helpURL); 
}
}
```

I get the following errors

```
error: IHM_PRO_CHIC is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
public class IHM_PRO_CHIC extends JFrame implements ActionListener,KeyListener {

../ihm_pro_chic/IHM_PRO_CHIC.java:202: error: method addTreeSelectionListener in class JTree cannot be applied to given types;
            tree.addTreeSelectionListener(this);
                ^
  required: TreeSelectionListener
  found: IHM_PRO_CHIC
  reason: actual argument IHM_PRO_CHIC cannot be converted to TreeSelectionListener by method invocation conversion
```

My goal is to launch an event when a node is clicked twice.

Update: Apart from using interfaces, is there a faster way to respond upon node clicking?

Comment: you have to implement the interfaces methods

Comment: do you mean "implements Interfaces"?

Comment: yes otherwise the code won't work

Comment: It actually returns the same error plus "cannot find symbol Interfaces"

Comment: please update your code to reflect your changes

Comment: that is not how to implement interface methods

Comment: Could you help me on that? Thanks :)

Comment: it is hard to discuss this here. it is better if you understand more about interfaces http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm